# How to add the logged in user email in a field in the model directly without using a view in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a field in my model as shown below

```
uploaded_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

This field will store the username (email in this case) of the user who has uploaded the data. As you can see that this is non editable so there is no way the user can edit it. The data has to be entered from the admin pannel. I wanted to know if there is any way to fill this field with the username of the loged in user who is uploading the data. I know if I use the view I can do some thing like

```
uploaded_by = request.user
```

So is there a way to do the same directly in the model so that I can use the admin pannel directly to store the username without using a view.

Comment: @ArunT yes I did thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why recreate when someone has already made a library

You can use [django-currentuser](https://pypi.org/project/django-currentuser/)
You just need to do this in your `models.py`

```
from django_currentuser.middleware import (
    get_current_user, get_current_authenticated_user)

# As model field:
from django_currentuser.db.models import CurrentUserField
class Foo(models.Model):
    created_by = CurrentUserField()
    updated_by = CurrentUserField(on_update=True)
```

Also, don't forget to add the middleware in `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
    ...,
    'django_currentuser.middleware.ThreadLocalUserMiddleware',
)
```

While this doesn't exactly save the user's email, it will save the user's reference, which is even better, you get all the user's details by doing `created_by.email` etc

Answer (score 0):

The save method can do this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.uploaded_by = self.your_user
    return super( your_model , self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what should i write in "your user" ?